# java program that asks user to inputs second largest and largest numbers

Tags: java

```
//java program that asks user to input a number and print the 1st and 2nd largest numbers

import java.util.Scanner;

public class twolargestnum
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

        int largest_2=0; //initializes second number
        int largest=0; //initializes first number
        int number;
        int counter=0;//initializes counter



        while(counter<10)
        {
            System.out.println("enter the number:");
            number=input.nextInt();//prompts user

            if(largest<number){
            largest=number;//stores number to largest
            largest_2=largest;}//stores largest to second largest or         largest_2
            else{

            if(largest_2<number &&largest>largest_2)
            largest_2=number; //stores second largest to number


            }
            counter=counter+1;//counts number input 10 times
    }

        System.out.println("The first largest number is "         +largest);//displays largest number inputed
    System.out.println("The second largest number is " +largest_2);//displays second largest number inputed

     }

}
```

**Output**

```
enter the number:
99
enter the number:
88
enter the number:
77
enter the number:
66
enter the number:
55
enter the number:
44
enter the number:
33
enter the number:
22
enter the number:
11
enter the number:
10
The first largest number is 99
The second largest number is 99
```

As you can see , the program displays the second largest number as 99 instead of 88. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

At the very least swap these two lines:

```
        largest=number;//stores number to largest
        largest_2=largest;//stores largest to second largest or
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `largest_2` to `largest` BEFORE you update `largest`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic mistake.

```
largest = number;
largest_2 = largest;
```

You are essentially changing (deleting) the stored value for *largest* when you perform the first operation. @Ishamael is correct in saying you need to switch these two statements. The logic is that you are changing *largest* to *number* (which deletes the old largest) and then trying to assign a new variable (*largest_2*) to a deleted value. Where you need to use *largest_2* to hold the value of *largest* **before** changing it's value.